# angular 2 successive calls to web api does not return updated resultset

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

When I make a call for the first time to my web api

```
GetAssignedRoles/{userID}
```

it works for the first time. Subsequent calls return the same result set until I make a call to another method before coming to make the call to this method again

```
[HttpGet("GetAssignedRoles/{userID}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAssignedRoles(string userID)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userID);
        IList<string> roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        List<UserRole> userRoles = new List<UserRole>();
        foreach(var item in roles)
        {
            userRoles.Add(await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(item));
        }
        IEnumerable<UserRoleViewModel> roleViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserRole>, IEnumerable<UserRoleViewModel>>(userRoles);
        return new OkObjectResult(roleViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Yes because the result set is cached by default

Comment: @Jinish How do refresh the resultset?